# Pause and resume CADisplayLink between storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-loop, cadisplaylink

I have a CADisplayLink set up for my gameloop that handles the animation loop.

When the game is over I show another storyboard with the game result.
At that storyboard the user can choose to Try again. And if so I choose to show the game storyboard again.

How do I pause and resume the CADisplayLink in the correct way?
Or should I destroy the CADisplayLink and create a new when the game starts again?

Answer (score 0):

How about setting an `isRunning` property which, if set to `NO` should force `CADisplayLink`'s handler method to return right away (without calling the code that makes the animation and the game run).

```
-(void) tick:(CADisplayLink*)
{
    if (!self.isRunning) return;

}
```

Comment: Thanks. What about memory consumption? Is this ok? And if the game is running in the background, is this ok?

Comment: I solved it when I removed the gameloop when the game is over by calling:
[updater removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];